# Why the cout will change the list address?

Tags: c++, list, cout

I want to generate the list and print the val by

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;


/**
* Definition for singly-linked list.
* struct ListNode {
*     int val;
*     ListNode *next;
*     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
* };
*/
struct ListNode{
    int val;
    ListNode *next;
    ListNode(int x) :val(x), next(NULL){
    }
};
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* mergeTwoLists(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {

    }
};

ListNode* geneate_list(vector<int> data){
    ListNode *p1, *p2;
    if (data.size() <= 0){
        p1 = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        return p1;
    }
    /*ListNode *p1, *p2;*/
    ListNode head(data[0]);
    p2 = &head;
    for (int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++){
        p1 = (ListNode*)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        p1->val = data[i];
        p1->next = NULL;
        p2->next = p1;
        p2 = p1;
    }
    return &head;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> data = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    ListNode* head = geneate_list(data);
    ListNode * g = head;

    while (head!=NULL){
        cout << head->val;
        head = head->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

then I find ,when cout ,the head's address change totally.
before

[image]

after

[image]

So,anyone can explain this?thx

Comment: Your `geneate_list` invokes *undefined behavior* by returning the address of a function local variable (whose lifetime ends after the function returns)

Comment: More or less unrelated, but why do you use `malloc` in a C++ program?

Answer (score 1):

The `generate_list` function is wrong for several reasons:

1. You return the address of a local variable which yields in undefined behaviour. Google *return the address of a local variable* for more details.
2. If you pass an empty vector to `generate_list`, the content of the head of the newly generated list is not initialized. But anyway as the list is empty, you cannot have a head anyway. What would `val` contain? Therefore `generate_list` must return NULL for an empty vector.
3. You are using `malloc` for allocating an object with a constructor. The constructor of ListNode will therefore never be called (although this constructor is not very useful here).

You want something like this:

```
ListNode* geneate_list(vector<int> data) {
  ListNode *head = NULL;
  ListNode *previous = NULL;

  for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    ListNode *p = new ListNode(0);

    if (i == 0)
      head = p;

    p->val = data[i];
    p->next = NULL;

    if (previous)
      previous->next = p;

    previous = p;
  }

  return head;
}
```

Disclaimer: this a more or less a C function as close as possible to the original function. In C++ you would do this differently.

Comment: Please, please change `malloc` to `new`. You cannot create an object with user-defined constructor with `malloc`.

Comment: @TadeuszKopec you are right, I modified the answer.